# Why doesn't str.endsWith("-") return true?

Tags: javascript

My function to truncate a string has to meet certain criteria, but I'm having trouble with some of them.

**Trying to satisfy these conditions**

```
truncateString("A-tisket a-tasket A green and yellow basket", 11)
```

should return `"A-tisket..."`.

```
truncateString("Peter Piper picked a peck of pickled peppers", 14)
```

should return `"Peter Piper..."`.

```
truncateString("A-tisket a-tasket A green and yellow basket", "A-tisket a-tasket A green and yellow basket".length)
```

should return `"A-tisket a-tasket A green and yellow basket"`.

```
truncateString("A-tisket a-tasket A green and yellow basket", "A-tisket a-tasket A green and yellow basket".length + 2)
```

should return `"A-tisket a-tasket A green and yellow basket"`.

**This is the one that I'm having trouble satisfying**

```
truncateString("A-", 1)
```

should return `"A..."`.

```
truncateString("Absolutely Longer", 2)
```

should return `"Ab..."`.

Test snippet of my code:

```js
function truncateString(str, num) {
  // Clear out that junk in your trunk
  
  var truncated = str.substr(0, num);
  var trunky = str;

  if (truncated.endsWith("-") == true) {
    return truncated.substr(0, (num) - 3) + "...";
  } else if (truncated.endsWith("i") == true) {
    return truncated.substr(0, (num) - 3) + "...";
  } else if (truncated.endsWith("b") == true) {
    return truncated.substr(0, (num)) + "...";
  } else if (truncated.endsWith('/-') == true) {
    return truncated.substr(0, (num)) + "...";
  } else
    return str;
}

var test = "A-tisket a-tasket A green and yellow basket";
console.log(truncateString(test, test.length));
```

Comment: Wouldn't `return truncated.substr(0,(1)-3)+"...";}` be the same as `truncated.substr(0,-2)+"...;`?

Comment: When `num` is 1, `num-3` is negative, and what does `substr(0, num-3)` do then?

Comment: What *do* you get instead of the expected results? In the first case, you're passing a negative number (1 - 3) to `substr` as the second parameter, which results in an empty string.

Comment: You can remove the `== true`, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Mozilla developer documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr), the function `String.prototype.substr` can take in a start and a length.

In your case, you are truncating `"A-"` to `"A"` by applying `"A-".substr(0, 1)` and thus it will not pass the test in your title: `truncated.endsWith("-")`.